# How Can I Link Firebase Phone Authentication with Email/Password Authentication?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create an app in which after a user types his email/ password they are saved in the firebase then the user enters his phone number on which otp is sent and the user is logged in after verification.my problem is that when both of these steps are completed firebase is creating two separate accounts one with email other with the phone. Please Tell me how can I create a Single account with Both Email/Password and Phone.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using multiple Firebase authentication providers then you need to link them, so both phone and email will create on single account.

First you can get the credentials:

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
```

then using `linkwithCredentials()` you will be able to link them:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking

Comment: Can you show us the whole answer, first sign up with email then use the phone auth to link into the existing email because there is an issue with PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(VerificationId, code); - which is being used at phone auth

Comment: it's late, but I successfully link phone Auth with email.  can you please describe which problem are you facing if you still need this.

Comment: can i know what is updateUI in method definition here?

Comment: @PitchaiMari the code provided is from the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account `updateUI()` is basically a method you have to create to update the ui according to what you want

Comment: Will this remove the ability to sign in using email/password? Just like when linking it with social like Google or Facebook? Thanks